# Facebook integration

Tags: social-network

I am currently developing a real estate website, and the client wants to push a notification to his Facebook page when he edits or adds a real estate.

How can I achieve this, with a module or hard-coded?

Comment: https://apps.facebook.com/rssgraffiti/ add this app in your facebook and then add the rss feed of your website, that's it !!!

Comment: Thank you Bala. The ideal solution is to have a checkbox so the user could select which information will be posted to facebook. For example the user posts 3 news on the website but wants to post to facebook just the first one. (sorry i wasn´t very clear on my question).

Answer (score 1):

[Post It Everywhere](https://drupal.org/project/postiteverywhere) just one click and your content will be posted to:

- Facebook
- Twitter
- LinkedIn
- FriendFeed

The most common way to make your site popular is by posting your content to different social networks. Here is a new and simple way for publishing content to different social networks.

> Features:
>
> - The link "Post it Everywhere!" will be displayed with every node type(the admins select). This link will be used to post on all the
>     networks
> - Authenticate Once, Use Forever: The users don’t have to authenticate every time when they login to the site or want to post
>     content. Each user will authenticate himself only once and these saved
>     settings will be used to post in the future.
> - The users will not be moved to other sites to post the content (as it happens in various modules that users are redirected to that
>     social network on which they want to post).
> - The user names and passwords of users are not saved for this purpose so no risk for security and spoofing.
> - Facebook Connect API is used to send posts to Facebook and OAuth is used to connect to LinkedIn, Twitter and FriendFeed. OAuth API can
>     be downloaded from this link.
> - End users can update their settings at anytime.

Comment: Wow thanks man. Also need to post to google plus (actually need to post only to three platforms: facebook, google plus and twitter). But i will try this anyway, see how it works and then let you know. Thanks again!